# Convert Json File to data Frame

Tags: python, json, html-parsing

I am trying to read a json file which i saved from
https://www.mahindrausa.com/js/locations.js

```
import json
data=json.load(open('Mahindra.json'))
```

But I am receiving this error.
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Need help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I am trying to read the file using json.load(open(filename)), however it is throwing an error..   raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Answer (score 0):

You can't just take the raw data. You have to modify it so it looks like this.

```
[  {
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    52.743356,
    -111.546907
  ]
},
"properties": {
  "dealerName": "Smiths Equipment Sales (Smiths Hauling)",
  "address": "HWY 13 - 5018 Alberta Avenue",
  "city": "Lougheed",
  "state": "AB",
  "zip": "T0B 2V0",
  "country": "Canada",
  "website": "http://smithsequipsales.com/",
  "phone": "780-386-3842",
  "dealerCode": "SMI06",
  "tractor": true,
  "utv": false,
  "hp": false
}  },  {
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [36.16876,-84.07945]
},
"properties": {
  "dealerName": " Tommy's Motorsports",
  "address": "2401 N Charles G Seivers Blvd",
  "city": "Clinton",
  "state": "TN",
  "statename": "United States",
  "zip": "37716",
  "phone": "865-494-6500",
  "website": "https://www.tommysmotorsports.com/",
  "dealerCode": "TOM08",
  "tractor": true,
  "utv": false,
  "hp": false
  }
}
]
```